# Add id to menu items in wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, id

I'm using wp_nav_menu in Wordpress to create my navigation

The output is similar to this(I have removed href links)

```
    <nav id="pageNav">
        <ul id="menu-headernav" class="menu">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>         
    </nav>
```

I need to style each link separately.

How can I add an id to each (li) or (a) in the menu so I can style it.

Comment: Pretty sure there should be `ID`s unless you, a plugin, or your theme has done something to remove them.

Comment: It's a custom theme I'm doing from scratch. There is no id's and I'm sure I'm not doing anything to remove them. The currently selected li has a class but the rest don't

Comment: I just took a look at several sites I am developing and also tested this in my sandbox. The menus created by `wp_nav_menu` have `ID`s. I don't know what is happening in your case but something is peculiar to your site.

Comment: @SimonCooper: Can we have a direct link to your site?

Comment: The site is local. s_ha_dum was correct, code in the functions.php (that I'd taken from someone) was removing the id's. So the li have id's now put is it possible to change these id's.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you would need to use a [Custom Walker Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function)

I've found some code on the [Wordpress Suport Forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/customized-wp_nav_menu) which might be of some use:

**Walker Class** - [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jHEVK8yF)

```
class custom_nav_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
                global $wp_query;
                $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

                $class_names = $value = '';

                $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
                $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

                $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
                $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

                $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
                $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

                $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

                $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

                $item_output = $args->before;
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
                $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= '</a>';
                $item_output .= $args->after;

                $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }

        /**
         * @see Walker::end_el()
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param object $item Page data object. Not used.
         * @param int $depth Depth of page. Not Used.
         */
        function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) {
                $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
}
```

[Thread Source - WP Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function)

Output:

```
<ul>
   <li id="nav-item-1">
      <a href="link-1">
      </a>
   </li>
   <li id="nav-item-2">
      <a href="link-2">
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li id="sub-item-1">
            <a href="sub-link-1">
            </a>
         <li id="sub-item-2">
            <a href="sub-link-2">
            </a>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh that looks perfect. I can understand most php but that looks a little advanced for me. Any chance of an explanation of this code.

Comment: Sorted it, I can add span tags to the <a> with 'link_after' => '<span></span>',